# change event of html hidden field

Tags: jquery

I want to check the change of html hidden field using jquery and i tried for this but the change event did not worked.

Somebody has and idea how to handle this?

Comment: How and when does the field's value change?

Comment: add the jQuery tag to your question

Comment: A hidden field whose value changed would kind of cease to be a hidden field. Are you manipulating the hidden field in JavaScript? What are you trying to do??

Comment: The value of hidden field can change on change of dropdown and textbox

Answer (score 79):

The `change` event doesn't fire when the value is **programmatically** changed, if it did it would cause infinite loops in many situations.

If you need the event to fire, then trigger it when changing the value yourself using [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), like this:

```
$("#hiddenId").val("new value").change();
```

[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is a shortcut for [`.trigger("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or, if you *don't* want that `change` event to bubble for some reason, then use [`.triggerHandler("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/).

Comment: In my case, the code that programmatically changes the hidden field is written in a plugin - I can't change that easily. I was hoping just to have an observer on the hidden field, in some way... is it possible?

Answer (score -3):

in this case you know exactly, when the value changes (onchange of dropbox), because you change it by your code, so there is no need to catch an event.

simply call your reaction function in the onchange part of your dropbox event.

Comment: My case is i have written a function which use to check the value of all fields on the load of page and before unload it checks if values have changed then show some message. It is working fine with other controls but not working for hidden field

Comment: While that would work, it would cause problems when you start assigning additional listeners to the field's change event. If any additional handlers are attached to the event, you'd have to also manually call them. Similarly, if those additional handlers are later removed, you'll have to remember to stop manually calling them. Manually triggering the event instead of manually calling the handler(s) each time is simpler and more elegant, in my opinion.

Comment: @helle how can we do this for api level(SDK)