# Detecting change of a hidden input field

Tags: jquery

I was hoping for some advice on how to detect the change of value of a hidden input field using jquery.

```
  <input type='hidden'id='txtVar' value=''/>

    $(document).on('change', '#txtVar', function () {
    alert("called");
});
```

As it is at the moment I am not getting it right

Regards

Comment: Did ou saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067372/change-event-of-html-hidden-field

Comment: (-1) If you literally put "Detecting change of a hidden input field jquery" in Google (the combination of the title and the tag) you would get several duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work. But the thing is you have to fire  the event manually.

See my code below :

```
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
<input type='hidden'id='txtVar' value=''/>

$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#txtVar").val("1234").change();
});

$(document).on('change', '#txtVar', function () {
    alert("called");
});
```

Once you fire the event using `click` as shown above the alert `called` will be called.

FInd the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ku3xU/1/