# If Hidden Filed values change then Save button should be Enabled. If same value is entered the Save button should be disabled again

Tags: jquery

I am tring to disable/Enable save button based on the change in the form elements.
But when the hidden input field values change via a button select pop up , the save button is not affected.

Below is my code.
I am trying to serialize old form values and comparing against changed form values.But hidden filed values cant be serialized I guess.

```
  function toggleSave() {
           $('form')
            .each(function () {
                $(this).data('serialized', $(this).serialize())
            })
            .on('change input', function () {
                $(this)
                     .find('button.Save')
                        .prop('disabled', $(this).serialize() == $(this).data('serialized'))
                ;
            })
            .find('button.Save')
               .prop('disabled', true);

        }
```

The below code works perfectly for all the forms except where there are hidden fields.
Can someone suggest a solution.

Note : Hidden fields populate via a button click Select pop up window.## Heading ##

Comment: if one or more of these answers helped you, please mark them correct and/or upvote.

Comment: My hidden field is populated by a kendo grid window that pops up on button click.


<button type="button" class=" k-button k-grid-add" onclick="searchCountries()">

</button>

Comment: so you can make `onclick="searchCountries();$('#hidden-field-id').change();"` which was what I was alluding to in my answer. Note that you will have to put the Id of your actual hidden field in the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be more about trying to capture programmatic changes rather than changes to a hidden field.

As the [answer here states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067372/change-event-of-html-hidden-field#4067875), programmatic changes cannot be captured by the `.on('change'` listener. You can trigger the change event "manually" on the hidden field via javascript when you change it's value.

I don't see the javascript in your question that updates the hidden input but an example of calling the change event manually (which should work for you) is:

`$('input:hidden').val('a new value').change();`

Comment: I am trying to capture the values populated in the hidden field and compare them
but seems like there is no handler that can capture hidden field values change.



My hidden field is populated by a kendo grid window that pops up on button click.


<button type="button" class=" k-button k-grid-add" onclick="searchCountries()">

</button>

Comment: @Sonia - there's no handler to capture "programmatic" changes: i.e. the changes you make via javascript. However, since you're using javascript to make the changes it is easy to add a second statement in the same place that calls the `$('#my-hidden-field-id').change()` method, or do anything else you need to.

Answer (score 2):

When an input field is changed from another function the event listener on input does not work.
You need to trigger this event by yourself if you want to enter in your input function. In the following a snippet where you can verify that if you trigger the event input after clicking on the third button you enter in your function.

```js
var inputHiddenFields = 0;
$(function () {
  // count the number of hidden input fields
  inputHiddenFields = $('form :hidden').length;
  $('form').find('button.Save').prop('disabled', true);

  // set each hidden input data attribute isChanged to false
  $('form :hidden').each(function(index, ele) {
    $(this).data('isChanged', false);
  });

  $('form :hidden').on('input', function (e) {
    // set data attribute isChanged to true
    $(this).data('isChanged', true);

    // count the number of hidden input fields with data attribute isChanged set to  true
    var changedInputHiddenFields = $('form :hidden').filter(function(index, ele) {
      return $(this).data('isChanged');
    }).length;

    // compare the number of all hidden input fields with changed one
    $(this).parent().find('button.Save').prop('disabled', inputHiddenFields != changedInputHiddenFields);
  });

  $('#clickme').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#input2').val('test');
  });

  $('#clickmeandtrigger').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#input2').val('test').trigger('input');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<form action="z.html">
    <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">
    <input type="hidden"  id="input2" name="input1">
    <button class="Save">Save</button>
</form>
<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
<button id="clickmeandtrigger">Click Me And Trigger</button>
```

Comment: thanks but I am not able to compare the values in the hidden field , I need to enable save only when hidden field value changes.

Comment: @Sonia I updated my snippet so that instead of serialize the form I enable the save button only when all the hidden fields have been changed using a new attribute for each hidden field. Of course, you need to trigger the event  input like in the snippet...

Comment: @Sonia To handle a change event on your form reagrding an hidden field must take place only if you immediately after changing the value fire the input event:  $('#input2').val('test').trigger('input');