# How to sense when a javascript loads a value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an alert when a java script changes a value in a hidden input field.

How the page that I am trying to modify works is that when clicking on the name box a popup window appears to pull a name from the database table and that name is then placed in the name box along with a hidden id box. On page load the hidden field is empty. I need to sense when the field value changes from empty to a value.

What I have so far is

I am using the onblur to trigger the alert. I have tried onchange also.

```
  <input type='hidden' name='form_pid' value='<?php echo attr($patientid) ?>' onblur='alertpriorauth(this)'/>

 function alertpriorauth(field){

 if(field.value != '')
 {
    alert("box is filled");

    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden Fields does not Trigger on change event.So whenever you set the value of any hidden input element & want the change to be tracked, you explicitly have to tell jQuery to trigger change event on that hidden input element.

```js
$('#status').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
})

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#status').val("Tushar").trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='hidden' val='' id="status" />
<button>Changed hidden value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  alert("hi");
$('#new_id').change(function(){
  

 if($('#new_id').val() != '')
 {
    alert("box is not empty");

    }
  
  });
  
});
</script>
```

```html
 <input type='hidden' name='form_pid' id="new_id" value='<?php echo attr($patientid) ?>'/>
```

Comment: Excuse me, why onBlur if it's a hidden field? Why not onChange ?

Comment: I have tried the script above and it does not produce the results that I am looking for. When the page loads the hi pops up but when the value is changed via the other java script. The second alert is not triggered.

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067372/change-event-of-html-hidden-field. It can't be done is the short version.